# Remove an element create by tinymce plugin

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have created a plugin in tinymce that adds an image in front of a text to alert the readers.
([Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0QEN.png))

Insert this div, and modify the content inside works fine, but if my users want to delete that div (all the red border), it's harder.

I want my user to click on the "danger sign" and press DEL to remove the element. (actually not possible)
How am I suppose to add this in my plugin  ?

here is my plugin :

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('picto', function (editor, url) {
    editor.contentCSS.push(url + '/css/picto.css');


    if (tinymce.majorVersion == 5) {

        editor.ui.registry.addIcon('addwarning', '<img src="' + url + '/img/attention.png" style="width:24px ; height:24px;">');
    }

    function addWarning() {
        var selection = editor.selection;
        var node = selection.getNode();
        if (node) {
            editor.undoManager.transact(function () {
                var content = selection.getContent();
                if (!content) {
                    content = 'Contenu';
                }

                selection.setContent('<br><div class="alert-modop">' + content + '</div><br>');
            });
        }
    }
```

here is my js call to editor :

```
<script> 
            tinymce.init({
                selector: 'textarea#contenuEtask',
                relative_urls: false,
                language: 'fr_FR',
                contextmenu: false,
                browser_spellcheck: true,
                plugins: "noneditable wordcount autolink anchor fullscreen lists advlist link image hr tabfocus table searchreplace spoiler picto",
                toolbar1: 'fullscreen | undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline| link image table | bullist numlist outdent indent ',
                toolbar2: 'alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | fontselect fontsizeselect forecolor backcolor | spoiler-add spoiler-hide spoiler-close | warning-add new-add note-add |hr searchreplace',
                noneditable_noneditable_class: "mceNonEditable",
                menubar: "",
                height: 500,
                setup: function (editor) {
                    editor.on('init', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val();
                        this.setContent(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('keyup', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });
                    editor.on('click', function () {
                        var tinyHtml = this.getContent();
                        $('.TinyHiddenValue input[type=hidden]').val(tinyHtml);
                    });
                }
            });
            tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', true, 'contenuEtask');
        </script>
```

and my css to create this element :

```
.alert-modop {
  background: url("../Sources/Images/attention.svg") no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks for help. o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who would have the same difficulty as me, I have an interesting solution.

I've surrounded my content with a div with content editable to true. 
This will have no impact on your plugin, but my content can now be selected.

```
selection.setContent('<br><div contenteditable="true" style="display: inline-block"><div class="alert-modop">' + content + '</div></div><br>');
```